# bootstrap-datepicker event onchange not update enddatepicker startDate: value in second time

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

```
"use strict";
let nowDate = new Date();
let today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
let enddate;

 $('#startdatepicker').datepicker({
      autoclose:true,
      todayHighlight: true,
      startDate:today
    }).on("changeDate",function(e){

        let present=new Date(e.date);
        enddate = new Date(present.getFullYear(), present.getMonth(), present.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);


        $('#enddatepicker').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         startDate: enddate
        });

    });
```

Comment: give us more details , is it enter into the onchange function on the second time?

Comment: on second time when $("#startdatepicker") change i would like $("#enddatepicker") to update. however it only update on first event only can u pls tell me why?

Comment: something like from to datepicker but when choose from datepicker then to datepicker not allow the past date

Comment: still no effect yet

Comment: did you debug it?

Comment: console.log() i did it end up like .on event working but seems like $('#enddatepicker').datepicker() create each object when event is trigger so that many $('#enddatepicker').datepicker(). js engine confuse to work and only work once i guess. is there any solution for that?

Comment: can you show me your entire code for this , including HTML

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hein_dev/juzLsgra/
here but im sorry some css links are broken down cause i create this urgent.

Comment: as first time let's say i choose 28 for from and then i choose 29 for to. After that as second time choosing for from  i choose29 again then 29 for to still avaliable to choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change onchange to 'change' , and your date not coming from the event variable , you need to get him 'manually' like this :

```
    "use strict";
let nowDate = new Date();
let today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
let enddate;

 $('#startdatepicker').datepicker({
      autoclose:true,
      todayHighlight: true,
      startDate:today
    }).on("change",function(e){

    var fromDate = $('#startdatepicker').val().split("/");
    let present=new Date(fromDate[2] , fromDate[1] - 1 , fromDate[0]);
    enddate = new Date(present.getFullYear(), present.getMonth(), present.getDate() + 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    alert(enddate);

        $('#enddatepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', enddate );
        });
```